# How to get .HLP file dynamically at run time Using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to open .HLP file by button click. i don't want to call .hlp from local folder like C:\ drive. i don't know where should i put .hlp file in my project. Please tell me with sample code.
i used this code :

```
Help.ShowHelp(this,"C:/Users/pushparajs/Downloads/TabbedMdiChildForms_src/TabbedMDIChildForms/helpfile/Properties/TTYUI.HLP");
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to specify the full path. Normally you just specify the file name, e.g. `"TTYUI.HLP"`, and `Help.ShowHelp(this, "TTYUI.HLP")` is smart enough to look in the same folder as `Application.ExecutablePath`.

You can add a reference to your hlp file in your solution explorer, and open properties by right clicking, and specify to copy to output folder.